# How to build 32 bit apk with Ant?

Tags: android, ant, shared-libraries, apk

I have an apk that uses 32bit so libraries. When build with Android.mk, I can set LOCAL_MULTILIB := 32 in the mk file, and then the built apk can work on a 64bit device. But now I want to build the apk with ant. Can anyone tell me how to write the ant script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are talking about apk, there is nothing like 32 bit or 64 bit on android. Once generated the apk should work on all supported device.